# Ajax json data not being loaded into datastore

Tags: extjs

My datastore works when I have a configuration member of 'data: ...raw json' inside the data store but when I try to load it via ajax it doesn't work.

```
 new Ext.data.Store({
        model: "SearchResult",
        proxy: {
            type: "ajax",
            url : "test.php",
            extraParams : 'test',
            reader: {
                type: "json",

            }
        },

    });
```

Note: test.php gets called according to chrome and echoes out:

```
{stock: 'Tommy', storePhone: '353535', year: '1984', make: 'Ferrari', trim: 'trim', miles: '12345', storename: 'branch name' },{stock: 'Tommy', storePhone: '353535', year: '1984', make: 'Ferrari', trim: 'trim', miles: '12345', storename: 'branch name' },{stock: 'Tommy', storePhone: '353535', year: '1984', make: 'Ferrari', trim: 'trim', miles: '12345', storename: 'branch name' }
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide the code for your Model? How have you determined that it doesn't work - are exceptions being thrown? Try registering some exception handlers for your store. Try stepping through the store load code in a debugger.

Comment: I know the model is correct because when I put the json data manually into the datastore using the 'data:' configuration parameter everything works. I have determined the code isn't working because the data should be loaded into a list and it doesn't appear. I am not well versed in exception handlers, no errors appear to be present in the chrome debugging console. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you encode your data as json in php ? 
like this echo json_encode($data);
It's either that or the model is completely different from the response.

A json format would look like this

```
{'success':true,'values':[{stock: 'Tommy', storePhone: '353535', year: '1984', make: 'Ferrari', trim: 'trim', miles: '12345', storename: 'branch name' },{stock: 'Tommy', storePhone: '353535', year: '1984', make: 'Ferrari', trim: 'trim', miles: '12345', storename: 'branch name' },{stock: 'Tommy', storePhone: '353535', year: '1984', make: 'Ferrari', trim: 'trim', miles: '12345', storename: 'branch name' }]}


reader:{
                    type: 'json',
                    root: 'values',
                }
```

Comment: The data being echoed from is in json format. I know the model is correct because when I put the json data manually into the datastore using the 'data:' configuration parameter everything works.

Answer (score 2):

> Note: test.php gets called according to chrome and echoes out:
>   {stock:
>   'Tommy', storePhone: '353535', year: '1984', make: 'Ferrari', trim:
>   'trim', miles: '12345', storename: 'branch name' },
>   {stock: 'Tommy',
>   storePhone: '353535', year: '1984', make: 'Ferrari', trim: 'trim',
>   miles: '12345', storename: 'branch name' },
>   {stock: 'Tommy',
>   storePhone: '353535', year: '1984', make: 'Ferrari', trim: 'trim',
>   miles: '12345', storename: 'branch name' }

And where are square brackets? For your store's config the response should look like

```
// Notice the square brackets
[
  {stock: 'Tommy', storePhone: '353535', year: '1984', make: 'Ferrari', trim: 'trim', miles: '12345', storename: 'branch name' }, 
  {stock: 'Tommy', storePhone: '353535', year: '1984', make: 'Ferrari', trim: 'trim', miles: '12345', storename: 'branch name' }, 
  {stock: 'Tommy', storePhone: '353535', year: '1984', make: 'Ferrari', trim: 'trim', miles: '12345', storename: 'branch name' }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a "data" wrapper for your JSON:

```
{"data":[... your JSON ...],"total":9999999,"success":true}
```

Comment: No, he doesn't. He hadn't specified record's `root` config. Docs are saying `By default the natural root of the data will be used. The root Json array`

Comment: yes but he still needs the [] brackets ... otherwise it won't be a json array

Comment: @nscrob, of course. I meant only `You need a "data" wrapper` part.

Comment: anyway .. either answer fixes his problem .. il gibe them an Up